# Why is UDP required at all when some protocols ride directly over IP?

Tags: tcp, udp, ip

As I understand it TCP is required for congestion control and error recovery or reliable delivery of information from one node to another and its not the fastest of protocols for delivering information.

Some routing protocols such as EIGRP and OSPF ride directly on top of IP. Even ICMP rides directly over IP.

Why is UDP even required at all? Is it only required so that developers/programmers can identify what application the inbound packet should be sent to based on the destination port number contained within the packet?

If that is the case then how is information gathered from protocols that ride directly on top of IP sent to the appropriate process when there is no port number information present?

Why are voice and video sent over UDP? Why not directly over IP?

(Note that I do understand thoroughly the use case for TCP. I am not asking why use UDP over TCP or vice versa. I am asking why use UDP at all and how can some protocols use directly the IP layer. Whats the added advantage or purpose of UDP over IP?)

Comment: There is no 'process' in the case of the other protocols, and therefore no need for a port number. The protocols are used by the IP stack itself. A port-oriented User Datagram Protocol with clearly defined semantics is required for application processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, IP and UDP are protocols on the different layers, IP by definition is Internet layer when UDP is [transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer). Layers were introduced to simplify network protocols architecture and to separate concerns. Application layer protocols are supposed to be based on transport layer (with some exceptions).

Most popular transport protocols (in IP network) are UDP and TCP. While TCP is feature rich but with many tradeoffs UDP is very simple but gives a lot of freedom and so typically is a base for other protocols.

The main feature of UDP is multiplexing: ports that allow multiple protocol instances (aka sockets) to coexist on the same node. This means that implementing your own protocol over IP instead of UDP either you won't be able to have multiple instances of your protocol on the same machine or you'll have to implement multiplexing yourself.

There're other features like segmentation and checksum. These features are not mandatory.

And as was mentioned in another answer there're lots of middleware like routers, NATs and firewalls that can ruin the idea of a custom "right over IP" protocol, but it's more like a collateral damage than a feature of UDP.

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes more sense in terms of *why is UDP useful* (than *why is UDP required*).

UDP is a recognized protocol by the [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority). UDP can be useful if you want to write a network protocol that's datagram based and you want to play more nicely with Internet devices.

Routers can have rules to do things like *drop any packet that doesn't make sense*. So if you try and send packets using say an unassigned IP protocol number between hosts separated by one or more routers, the packets may well never get delivered as you've intended. The same could happen with packets from an unrecognized UDP protocol but that's at least one less door to worry about whether your packet can make it through.

Internet endpoints (like *hosts*) may do similar filtering too. If you want to write your own datagram based protocol and use a typical host operating system, you're more likely to need to write your software as a privileged process if not as a kernel extension if you're trying to ride it as its own IP protocol (than if you'll be using UDP).

Hope this answer is useful!